# How to use two LocalStrategy?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

How to use two LocalStrategy, one for front end auth, another for back end auth?

```
// font end
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
}), function (email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({email: email}, function(err, user) {
        // ...
        done(null, user);
    });
});

// back end
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, function (username, password, done) {
    SysUser.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
        // ...
        done(null, user);
    });        
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
// frontend
passport.use('frontend-local', new LocalStrategy({
  ....
});

//backend
passport.use('backend-local', new LocalStrategy({
  ....
});
```

Then, wherever you want to use one strategy, in a route, just call it like:

```
app.post('/frontend/login',
  passport.authenticate('frontend-local'),
  ...
```

and similarly for backend.